# SecTrustPolicy fail with self-signed cert

Tags: ssl, alamofire, self-signed

So I created this test case (a mish mash of existing alamofire test cases):

```
func testHTTPBasicAuthenticationWithValidCredentialsSelfSignedSuccess() {
    // Given
    let expectation = expectationWithDescription("\(URLString) 200")

    var request: NSURLRequest?
    var response: NSHTTPURLResponse?
    var data: NSData?
    var error: NSError?

    setRootCertificateAsLoneAnchorCertificateForTrust(serverTrust)
    let policies = [SecPolicyCreateBasicX509()]
    SecTrustSetPolicies(serverTrust, policies)

    // When
    Alamofire.request(.GET, URLString)
        .authenticate(user: user, password: password)
        .response { responseRequest, responseResponse, responseData, responseError in
            request = responseRequest
            response = responseResponse
            data = responseData
            error = responseError

            expectation.fulfill()
    }

    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(defaultTimeout, handler: nil)

    // Then
    XCTAssertNotNil(request, "request should not be nil")
    XCTAssertNotNil(response, "response should not be nil")
    XCTAssertTrue(data?.length > 0, "Data not found.")
    XCTAssertNil(error, "error should be nil")

}
```

The Root CA is a self-signed cert for an existing sight that works.

But I get this error back:

> Test Suite 'Selected tests' started at 2015-08-12 12:46:37.512 Test
>   Suite 'StageAuthentication' started at 2015-08-12 12:46:37.514 Test
>   Case '-[Alamofire_iOS_Tests.StageAuthentication
>   testHTTPBasicAuthenticationWithValidCredentialsSelfSignedSuccess]'
>   started. 2015-08-12 12:46:37.663 xctest[3641:12220875]
>   NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
>   /Users/wynne_b/Alamofire/Tests/QuestAuthentication.swift:309: error:
>   -[Alamofire_iOS_Tests.StageAuthentication testHTTPBasicAuthenticationWithValidCredentialsSelfSignedSuccess] :
>   XCTAssertNotNil failed - response should not be nil
>   /Users/wynne_b/Alamofire/Tests/QuestAuthentication.swift:310: error:
>   -[Alamofire_iOS_Tests.StageAuthentication testHTTPBasicAuthenticationWithValidCredentialsSelfSignedSuccess] :
>   XCTAssertTrue failed - Data not found.
>   /Users/wynne_b/Alamofire/Tests/QuestAuthentication.swift:311: error:
>   -[Alamofire_iOS_Tests.StageAuthentication testHTTPBasicAuthenticationWithValidCredentialsSelfSignedSuccess] :
>   XCTAssertNil failed: "Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The
>   certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a
>   server that is pretending to be “portal.care180.com” which could put
>   your confidential information at risk."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is
>   invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be
>   “portal.care180.com” which could put your confidential information at
>   risk., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the
>   server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x7ae21c60 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork
>   Code=-1202 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0,
>   _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9813, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=,
>   kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates={type = immutable, count = 1, values = (   0 :
>    )}}}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://portal.care180.com/services/init.json,
>   NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey={type =
>   immutable, count = 1, values = (  0 :  )},
>   NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0,
>   NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://portal.care180.com/services/init.json}" -
>   error should be nil Test Case
>   '-[Alamofire_iOS_Tests.StageAuthentication
>   testHTTPBasicAuthenticationWithValidCredentialsSelfSignedSuccess]'
>   failed (0.156 seconds). Test Suite 'StageAuthentication' failed at
>   2015-08-12 12:46:37.671.   Executed 1 test, with 3 failures (0
>   unexpected) in 0.156 (0.157) seconds Test Suite 'Selected tests'
>   failed at 2015-08-12 12:46:37.672.     Executed 1 test, with 3 failures
>   (0 unexpected) in 0.156 (0.160) seconds Program ended with exit code:
>   1

Sorry for being dense: what am I doing wrong? Or is there an Alamofire test that does this with a different cert and host?

Answer (score 0):

I confused the root and the leaf. My bad.